# webscraping an image with python but can't find image

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I'm trying to scrape stockcharts.com for the chart image from a url. For example from: http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=AMZN

however, when inspecting the element in question, it is not a proper image src with a .jpg, .png, etc. suffix. For example the element in question from the above link is:http://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=AMZN&p=D&b=5&g=0&i=0&r=1479451634864

and therefore when I try to use the following code in python 2.7, I get an empty file in the directory sharing the script:

```
import urllib
url = "http://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=AMZN&p=D&b=5&g=0&i=0&r=1479451634864"
filename = "testimg.jpg"
urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Is this a javascript rendered page, or is there something that I'm missing? A reference to elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The site checks `User-Agent` header; It allows specific user-agents only.

You need to change the header to fetch the image. Otherwise, the site returns a 403 Forbidden response.

[`urllib.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) does not accept additional headers, you need to use [`urllib2.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) / [`urllib2.Request`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) to specify custom headers and save file yourself:

```
import urllib2

url = "http://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=AMZN&p=D&b=5&g=0&i=0&r=1479451634864"
filename = "sc.png"
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
u = urllib2.urlopen(req)
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(u.read())
```

Comment: @downvoter, How can I improve the answer? Please let me know what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: @JRodDynamite, Thank you for the English corrections.

Comment: I assume you have windows 7 64 bit like me. I click on the link in your first sentence and get a new page with the chart. I right click on the chart and choose "save as" and the filename of the image file is "sc.png" not "testimg.jpg"

Comment: @Marichyasana, I changed the filename (which to be used for local filename after download). Thank you for the feedback.